# Drupal is "forgetting" my password -- where should I start?

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, drupal, drupal-7

I have a Drupal 7 site that's started displaying erratic behavior.

Specifically, I nearly always have to reset my password when I log out of the site -- if I've been logged in for a while.

The logs aren't helpful. The password reset link works and that's what I've been using.

It happens to all accounts.

Where should I even start looking?

Edit: I'm on Drupal 7.50

Comment: You probably want to ask this on Drupal Stackexchange! http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you login at least once, after you set new password. I think that you should start from determining is password stored badly or it's been changed after some time.